# How to install GDS plugin in a Neo4j virtual machine created in Azure?

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

I have a project working in my laptop. My data is in Neo4j desktop database. I also use the plugin Graph Data Science (GDS)

I would like to work in a Neo4j VM but I have to install GDS in the VM.

I looked here in the documentation: https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/installation/

But I don't understand how to install GDS in my VM deployed in Azure.

How do I have to do it ?

Comment: I am having trouble with the same exact thing